# Customisations in bible index (bibleref, imakeidx)

Tags: imakeidx, bibleref

I have to print a biblical index according the Greek Bible (the so called "LXX"). To do so I modified the package bibleref

[Package Bibleref_LXX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nnka5c82lhwd6d/bibleref_LXX.sty?dl=0)

Now I should do a couple of customisations, but actually I don't know whether I have to work on bibleref or on imakeidx:

1. I need to suppress the indent of the book titles
2. I should have smallcaps instead of uppercase for the numbers of the
   books (in my MWE "Ad Corinthios \textsc{i}" instead of "Ad
   Corinthios I"

For the point #1, I tried to set the \parindent via \indexsetup, but it didn't work.

For the point #2 I tried to change (in the bibleref package) alle the names of the books in the form Nameofthebook \textsc{i}, but something goes wrong on the \biblerefmap (from row 980 of the modified package)

MWE:

```
   \documentclass[10pt, twoside, openany]{book}%openany
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\unicodefont{Garamond Premier Pro} 
    \newfontfamily\ItalicFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
    \newfontfamily\SlantedFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
    \setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}          
    \usepackage{polyglossia}                    
        \setmainlanguage{italian}

    \usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
                language=auto,
                indexing=true,
                backend=biber,
            ]{biblatex}

    \usepackage{bibleref_LXX}   
            \renewcommand*{\biblerefindex}{\index[rif]}

    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}

    \makeindex[name=rif,title=Indice dei riferimenti biblici, columns=1]

    \begin{document}
    Mt \ibiblechvs{Mt}(13:24-30)\\
    Mt \ibiblechvs{Mt}(14:12)\\
    Rom \ibiblechvs{Rom}(1:18)\\
    Io \ibiblechvs{Io}(15:27)\\
    Ap \ibiblechvs{Ap}(2:12)\\
    Jos \ibiblechvs{Jos}(5:13-15)\\
    1Cor \ibiblechvs{1Cor}(2:10)\\
    Is \ibiblechvs{Is}(11:2)\\
    Is \ibiblechvs{Is}(12:1)\\


    \printindex[rif]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: #2 must have something to do with \def\br@ICorinthians{\BRepistlenumberstyle{1}Cor\BRperiod}%

Comment: In any case, you should not create your own package which pastebin the code of the main package. Because when the new version of bibleref will be released, you won't have the new feature. You should create your package with only your specific code, and use \RequirePackage to call the main package.

Comment: use \renewcommand*{\BRbooknumberstyle}[1]{\textsc{\romannumeral##1} }%
\renewcommand*{\BRepistlenumberstyle}[1]{\textsc{\romannumeral##1} }%

Comment: you should send me a email, because I thinks yourd need could be directly integrated to bibleref

Comment: Interesting. But I need your mail address. Mine is syldor@mac.com

Comment: the best way would be to open an issue to https://framagit.org/maieul/bibleref/issues

Comment: I tried, but the site seems to be full of bugs :(

Comment: sORRY? which bugs? all is ok for me.

Comment: No, I tried to make a post and upload a file twice (Mac OSX, Safari) always getting an error (504? can't remember)

Comment: Try without sending a file, but pastebin it as code.